# Visual Studio change C# method parameter colouring

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, syntax-highlighting

In Visual Studio 2013, is there a way to change the syntax colouring of C# method parameters?

e.g. Can I have AAA and BBB colored, but not someInt, Foo, ToString

```
private int MyMethod(int AAA, int BBB)
{
    int someInt = new int();
    someInt = AAA + BBB;
    string Foo = AAA.ToString();
}
```

I tried going to **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colours -> Text Editor** and changing **Identifier**, but this changed the coloring of just about everything (variables, methods, parameters).

Comment: I guess Power Tools extension lets you customize more stuff... I'd give it a try

Comment: Also look on how to customize the VS Theme.

Comment: It doesn't look like Power Tools can colour code in the text editor, but it adds mouse-click scrolling, which I have been looking for too.

Answer (score 12):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do this.

First, check this in ReSharper options:

[image: ReSharper options]

Then choose the color in the VS options:

[image: VS options]

End result:

[image]

Comment: Oops.  I only download free extensions, which was why I missed the Resharper option.  Thanks for pointing it out, @Lucas!

Comment: @JamesJensen This thing enhances VS is just about every conceivable way, calling it an *extension* doesn't do it justice. Once you try it you just can't go back. ;)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski So there isn't a way to do this nativley? I'm not about to buy ReSharper just for this functionality.  Curious as to why this is available for C++/CLI but not C#.

Comment: @ToastyMallows I don't know of any way to do this natively, but it should be easy enough to write a plugin just for that if you want, especially with Roslyn. But I encourage you to try R# if you haven't, you'll wonder how you lived without it before ;)

Comment: I'm stuck with a CodeRush subscription at work.  Is there any ability within CodeRush to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I recently found this extention while looking for the same thing for TypeScript, apparently it supports C# and VisualBasic, so it may be helpful for you and anybody else looking:

[Visual studio SemanticColorizer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fd89374f-892a-42d6-8207-da8fefa93fdf?SRC=VSIDE)

Comment: The linked extension is only available for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Also Codinion (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/504311cf-bd01-4b12-bca3-a3e5d9505b76) does semantic coloring. Available for both 2013 and 2015.

Comment: Update: at time of writing, SemanticColorizer supports MSVC 2015, 2017 and 2019.

Answer (score 1):

For VS 2017 you can use.

Enhanced Syntax Highlighting by Stanislav Kuzmich

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StanislavKuzmichArtStea1th.EnhancedSyntaxHighlighting

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do this in Visual Studio without any extension.

Here is VS 2022

[image]

Answer (score -6):

Unfortunately, you will not find a way to colorize parameter variables with the C# language.  You do have the option, however, of writing an extension to do just that. Or, you could rewrite everything in C++, where you can get your parameters colorized.

Comment: "Boss, we can't get our parameters colored the way we want." 
-------- 
"Well, I guess we have no choice but to rewrite our entire application in C++"

Comment: Now, why is this answer downvoted and why the snarky, illogical response?  Visual Studio 2013 does not easily support parameter colorization in the IDE (which is not your "application"), and the options I mentioned suggest that either (a) you write your own extension to color parameters in the IDE the way you want, or (b) you program in C++ (which, by the way, is an example of hyperbole and not stupidity).